# Use template with <function>

Tags: c++, class, templates, gcc

Im trying to make template class of a menu class, and i try to pass a T type, to be able to change the Argument class to make it for more uses

```
    template<class T>
    class Menu : public std::vector<std::tuple<uint8_t, std::wstring, std::function<void(T)>>> {
/**code over here**/
}
```

but every GCC give me an error

> ```
>  C:\Users\InfoLabA-PC04\Desktop\Ar\Arley.hpp:188:8: error: invalid parameter type 'void'
>    class Menu : public std::vector<std::tuple<uint8_t, std::wstring, std::function<void(T)>>> {
>          ^~~~
> ```

when i try to use it like

```
Menu<void> MenuName;
```

Comment: You can't pass a parameter that is `void`...

Comment: You should avoid to inherit from `std::vector` BTW, prefer composition.

Comment: I meant `template <..> class Menu { std::vector<..> data; };`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change your declaration to

```
template <typename... Ts>
class Menu : public std::vector<std::tuple<uint8_t,
                                           std::wstring,
                                           std::function<void(Ts...)>>> {
    // ...
};
```

and use it

```
Menu<> MenuName;
```

Comment: Thanks that solved all, and what do you mean with composition?